# Java jmap -heap command gave OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, tomcat, out-of-memory, jmap

We are periodically runnign jmap -heap  command to monitor a tomcat application. However this is first time when we got OutOfMemoryError.

When we monitor the memory at server level there is around 110MB available. Since it is just monitoring can we ignore this time assuming no harm has been done to the application and the server was low on memory when this command run?

```
$ ./jmap -heap 13511
Attaching to process ID 13511, please wait...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.runTool(JMap.java:179)
        at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.main(JMap.java:110)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
        at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:597)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal.<init>(LinuxDebuggerLocal.java:210)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.bugspot.BugSpotAgent.setupDebuggerLinux(BugSpotAgent.java:816)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.bugspot.BugSpotAgent.setupDebugger(BugSpotAgent.java:518)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.bugspot.BugSpotAgent.go(BugSpotAgent.java:493)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.bugspot.BugSpotAgent.attach(BugSpotAgent.java:332)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:163)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.HeapSummary.main(HeapSummary.java:39)
```

**UPDATE:** We tried to run jmap -heap  again and got java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Cannot create GC thread. Out of system resources.

So, the problem seems to be at OS resource level.

```
$ ./jmap -heap 13511
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Cannot create GC thread. Out of system resources.
#
#  Internal Error (gcTaskThread.cpp:38), pid=13162, tid=1104300352
#  Error: Cannot create GC thread. Out of system resources.
#
# JRE version: 6.0_18-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (16.0-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /data01/home/s618199/JAVA/jdk1.6.0_18/bin/hs_err_pid13162.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Aborted
```

Comment: Your application will go down if you get OOM so there is a big risk running jmap to produce heap dump periodically. -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError is better option to debug OOMs

Comment: @SameerNaik: We only want to monitor memory and don't want to produce heap dump. I didn't know if jmap -heap <pid> option produces heap dump.

Comment: See this. http://www.herongyang.com/Java-Tools/jstack-jmap-Generate-Heap-Dump-File.html It does produce heap dump. To monitor memory, you could use jmx based tools like jconsole.

Comment: @SameerNaik: Thanks. I thought not all options of jmap produces heap dump. I will research and stop using jmap for memory monitoring if -heap <pid> option also produces heap dump. We cannot use jconsole or jvisualm for monitor due to production environment limitation.

Comment: Based on my research only jmap -dump option produces the heap dump. Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html#options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a memory problem (even though it is reported as one) but an operating system resource problem: You can not create any more threads. And it seems to affect the *jmap* program and not Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. We cannot login to the server using putty session now. We are getting "-bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable".

Comment: Would you know if jmap -heap <pid> option produces heap dump or just analyze the memory of process and print the status?

Comment: It think it just prints a summary and status. Only `jmap -dump` creates a heap dump.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Thanks a lot. I already added the comment to question. Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html#options